# Why do I need to use Underscore.js _.bind method for Backbone.js custom events?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

```
var DocumentEventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function () {
    $(document).on('visibilitychange', _.bind(this.onVisibilityChange, this));
  },  
  onVisibilityChange : function () {
    console.log('inside onVisibilityChange');
  }
});
```

So why can't I just do $(document).on('visibilitychange', 'onVisibilityChange' ?

I know the bind method is to keep and pass the context of the method, but I don't care about the context, I am never using this in onVisibilityChange. Why $(document).on('visibilitychange', 'onVisibilityChange' does not work?

Comment: then you don't need to do it. If you don't need context, you don't need to bind it. But then, does it need to be a view method?

Comment: It doesn't work if I don't bind it and where would you put the event handler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This way the `this` object inside `onVisibilityChange` will be your view object.

If you don't need this, then don't use `_.bind`. The only problem is you will have to be very careful later, when you change your mind and use `this` inside `onVisibilityChange`: you will have a good chance to forget that `this` doesn't refer to the view object, and introduce some entertaining bugs into your code.

---

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/BmCwQ/) is a working example, with and without `_.bind`:

```
var  MyView1 = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            $(document).on('click', _.bind(this.onClick, this));
        },
        onClick: function () {
            console.log('inside onClick, "this" is ' + this.toString());
        },
        toString: function () {
            return "[object MyView1]";
        }
    }),
    myView1 = new MyView1(),
    MyView2 = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            $(document).on('dblclick', this.onDblClick);
        },
        onDblClick: function () {
            console.log('inside onDblClick, "this" is ' + this.toString());
        },
        toString: function () {
            return "[object MyView2]";
        }
    }),
    myView2 = new MyView2();

console.clear();
$(document).click();
$(document).dblclick();
```

Output:

```
inside onClick, "this" is [object MyView1]
inside onDblClick, "this" is [object HTMLDocument]
```

I used `click` and `dblclick` events for the sake of simplicity. Output is written to the console, press F12. Tested in latest Chrome.

Comment: But it does not work when I don't use _.bind :/. That is my problem. I get a jQuery error.

Comment: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluationg '((x.event.special[o.origType]||{})handle||o.handler).apply(i.elem.a)')

Comment: This works for me: `$(document).on('visibilitychange', this.onVisibilityChange);`

Comment: Oh right, I was doing 'onVisibilityChange', instead of this.onVisibilityChange. I thought it worked like events where you could juste give the method inside ''.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Backbone, you shouldn't bother using jQuery. Try this:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.on('visibilityChange', this.onVisibilityChange);
},
```

Comment: Your example would only work if el was document. My view has a custom element.

Comment: @Maxwell: This is the default way in Backbone to listen to events regardless of what your views is (or el). In fact it works on Models as well as they extend from Event.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, it does not work :/. And it makes sense, on what element are you binding the visibilityChange event?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use _.bind then don't use it, and if you have problems solve it another way.

```
at = this;
$(document).on('visibilitychange', function(){at.onVisibilityChange();});
```

What _.bind do is just wrap function with another function, in that function just call original function with specified context.

**Edit** :

`$('selector').on('event',func)` calls function with context of $('selector')[0] (DOM element).